# Package Id in Sparx Enterprise Achitect

Tags: javascript, package, enterprise

I have problem with packages in EA. I have created a SQLQuery that returns a package by its name. The diagram 'Process 1' I want to create gets package ID that is the parent package not the selected one. If I use `Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();` instead I get the right package. I made a work around by creating a 'Dummy package' below 'My Package' and uses that instead '/My Package/Dummy Package/'. What is the problem?

Works (I select 'My Package' and run script):

```
var thePackage as EA.Package;
thePackage = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();

var diagram as EA.Diagram;
diagram = thePackage.Diagrams.AddNew("Process 1", "process");
diagram.Update();
```

This doesn't work (Diagram created one package above 'My Package'):

```
var collection as EA.Collection;
var thePackage as EA.Package;

collection = Repository.GetElementsByQuery("Package By Name", "My Package");
thePackage = collection.GetAt(0);

var diagram as EA.Diagram;
diagram = thePackage.Diagrams.AddNew("Process 1", "process");
diagram.Update();
```

Work around ('/My Package/Dummy Package/' diagram in 'My Package'):

```
var collection as EA.Collection;
var thePackage as EA.Package;

collection = Repository.GetElementsByQuery("Package By Name", "Dummy Package");
thePackage = collection.GetAt(0);

var diagram as EA.Diagram;
diagram = thePackage.Diagrams.AddNew("Process 1", "process");
diagram.Update();
```

Thank you!

Regards Patrik